# Non-linear optimisation and Lagrange multipliers to prove the minimum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

[I'm currently really struggling with some topics in my optimisation subject. My finals are still a few weeks away but I'm trying to make a start on studying now. Similar questions to this one keep coming up in my set problems and I don't really know what to do. Could anyone help me out so I can complete a few of the other questions like this? I'm almost certain something similar will be on the exam.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mdli.png)

Comment: I forgot to add, I need to use Lagrange multipliers to answer this.

Comment: You should include your attempt.

Comment: Hint: Let $\mathbf{y} = [ x_{1}^2 ... x_{N}^2]^{\top}$ and $\mathbf{a} = [ a_{1} ... a_{N}]^{\top}$. Note that $\mathbf{y} \geq 0$. The problem is now LP. Investigate the dual of this LP to prove.

Answer (score 0):

The lagrangian

$$
L(X,\lambda) = \sum a_k x_k^2-\lambda\left(\sum x_k^2 - 1\right)
$$
has the stationary points given by the solutions to

$$
\cases{
(a_k-\lambda)x_k = 0, \ \ k = 1,\cdots,n\\
\sum x_k^2 - 1=0
}
$$  we have $n$ stationary points on

$$
\cases{
(x_i = \pm 1) \cap (x_k = 0, k\ne i)\\
a_i-\lambda = 0
}
$$

so the objective function value at each stationary point is given by $a_i$ then the sought stationary point is at $i^*$ such that $i^*= \arg\min a_i$